# Numlock on by default on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, numlock

I am fairly new to this version of Linux.

I have it set so that when it boots, it automatically boots into the GUI for the operating system. This means when I load up the OS I am greeted with a login screen. My question is how to have it so NumLock is on by default at this point.

I have looked at ways of doing it and most the ways involve using NumLockX. I have gone off several forums on how to do it, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/155683/491642), [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock), and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-linux-turn-on-num-lock-on-gnome-startup/). However they are for Ubuntu and Debian versions of Linux and they proved unsuccessful when I tried them on Kali. Is anyone aware of how to do it on Linux Kali? I would appreciate any help.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Kali, every time lock screen is on Nun Lock is off. My problem got solved after i changed Kali from XFORCE to GNOME.

Here is post on Kali page how to change to GNOME and related topics on that. https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/xfce-faq/

This is what worked for me and sorry i couldn't be of more Help (some detailed explanation with code how to solve this on XFORCE)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer but I'm afraid I asked this a long time ago and am no longer in a position to test. I dropped you a +1 though and hopefully it helps someone else :)